# Когда применяется sleep?

Tags: php

Я знаю, что это задержка в несколько миллисекунд.
Скажите, пожалуйста, когда применяется sleep в реальных проектах?

Comment: не в несколько, а в указанное количество. Можно применять, например, когда ваш скрипт парсит другие сайты, для того, чтобы делать паузы между запросами. Либо в каким то консольных выводах. Либо обращаетесь в цикле к некому АПИ, где установлен лимит обращений в минуту и т.п.

Comment: и не в миллисекунд, а очень даже секунд. Если надо меньше - usleep.

Comment: teran, уточните, пожалуйста, зачем задержка нужна, приведите, пожалуйста, пример в реальных проектах...
Зачем нужна пауза между запросами?
В яваскрипт похожая функция есть, которая выполняет сообщение через несколько минут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще есть функция `usleep($micro_seconds)` - аналогичная по действию ф-и `sleep($seconds)`, но принимающая в качестве аргумента значение в *микросекундах*.

Из моей практики, приостановка выпонения скрипта на заданный период бывает полезна:

- чтобы снизить нагрузку на интенсивно потребляемый скриптом ресурс(ы): **CPU** / **DB** / **...**
- чтобы снизить частоту запросов к внешнему ресурсу, который накладывает ограничения на их количество. Например - запрет доступа клиента к нему, при превышении им 100 запросов в течении 30сек.
- чтобы на порядок увеличить время, необходимое для проведения брутфорса на форму аутенфикации. Например, перед ответом о неверной аутенфикации - делать паузу в несколько секунд.
- для некоторых алгоритмов иногда требуется вставлять заданную паузу, для верной его реализации.

Например - требуется написать скрипт, который в бесконечном цикле каждые 10 секунд выводит **одно сообщение** `Прошло 10 сек!`:

Реализация:

```
<?php
while (true) {
    if (time() % 10 === 0) {
        echo "Прошло 10 сек!\n";
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

Если закомментировать строку с `sleep(1);`, то скрипт будет работать неверно - выводить несколько сообщения вместо одного, а также начнет потреблять очень много (почти 100%) ресурсов CPU.

**UPD:** на комментарий Ep1demic

Comment: Добавь еще ситуацию при работе с некоторыми API у которых проставлен Rate Limit, напр. не больше 100 запросов за 30 секунд...